# Why is the "sum" variable here not being updated with each iteration?

Tags: c, variables, syntax, scanf

I wrote this rather simple code in C to find out the average of 5 numbers:-

```
int main()
{
    int n,sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        sum += scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("avg =%d/n",(sum / 5));
    return 0;
}
```

However, it was not giving me the correct output.

So, after checking some of the statements I finally got the correct output with this code instead:-

```
int main()
{
    int n,sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &n);
        sum+=n;
    }
    printf("avg =%d\n", (sum / 5));
    return 0;
}
```

The only difference being that I did not update the sum directly by adding the scanned value to the sum variable as I did in the first case.Then I added a print statement within the loop in the first code to see what was going on and found out that instead of storing the sum of the inputs it was just storing the  entered value at that instance(Like if I enter 1 in 1st iteration then it is storing 1 and after that when I am entering 2 instead of storing 3 it is storing 2) and so on.

Can anyone explain why is this happening?

Comment: Please learn [what `scanf` actually returns](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value).

Comment: `scanf()` returns the number of assignments it executed (in your case `1`, or unlikely, depends on input `0`), or `EOF` in case of error.

Comment: Your first version is same as `for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { int num_parsed = scanf("%d", &n); sum += num_parsed;` which completely ignores the input that is stored in `n`.

Answer (score 2):

`scanf("%d", &n)` **stores** the scan'ed value in the memory pointed to by the pointer given after the format string, i.e. in the memory pointed to by `&n` which of cause is the variable `n`.

`scanf` **returns** the number of succesfully scan'ed items. In your case that would be 1 when the user inputs a valid integer number.

Consequently, it is `n` that must be added to `sum`. It is **not** the return value that shall be added. That's why the second solution is correct.

**BTW**

You should always check the value returned by `scanf` to make sure that you have scan'ed the correct number of items. Like:

```
int main()
{
    int n,sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1)
        {
            // Error - coud not read valid integer

            // Add some error handling or simply stop the program using
            exit(1);
        }
        sum+=n;
    }
    printf("avg =%d\n", (sum / 5));
    return 0;
}
```